# How to refresh content script for chrome extension as DOM changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm having a difficult time re-running some simple JS from a content_script for a chrome extension. Here's basically what I have setup. The following code works, but only once:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["https://www.amazon.com/*"],
    "js": ["./content_scraper.js", "./main.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  } ],
  "permissions": ["tabs","webNavigation"]
}
```

**content_scraper.js**

```
function dataUpdater() {
  // this function scrapes the page and updates the data var
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(message.type) {
      case "getItems":
        sendResponse(data)
        break;
    }
  }
);
```

**main.js**

```
 function getItemsData() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "getItems"}, function(resp) {
      resp.map(item => {
        // do some things
      }
    })
  }) 
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getItemsData)
```

So, the above code works after DOMContent is loaded. I have experimented with the DOMNodeInserted event and reading the `document.readyState` to fire scripts again, but I cannot seem to access the dataUpdater function from content_scripts.

I'm simply trying to run the content_scraper.js (which lives in content_scripts) whenever the DOM is updated. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1):

You need to look for `MutationObserver` and observe on `subtree` of document body, like this:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
...   
});
observer.observe(document.body, { subtree: true });
```

See the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: This returns an error > Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': The options object must set at least one of 'attributes', 'characterData', or 'childList' to true.